# Neo4j Cypher MERGE queries super slow, need help optimizing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am very new to Neo4j and Cypher. I have been evaluating Neo4j for the past several weeks as a replacement for our existing DB to be able to run more efficient queries for our use case. So we have come up with the best DB schema that fits our needs very well and the data fetching queries work very well. The problem I am facing is while inserting data into Neo4j.

MERGE queries are super slow and take a lot of CPU horsepower, and keeps getting slower with increasing Nodes. With only a couple Million Nodes, the MERGE queries take several minutes.

I have used MERGE everywhere because we do not desire same / similar Nodes for every request, as we have similar data coming in from multiple sources, and might get the same data multiple times.

I am using Python and the Neo4j Python library to interact. I have a lot of JSON data coming in via APIs, which is then filtered and normalized in Python before inserting into Neo4j.

Details of what I am doing :

- The main (Base) Node will be connected to all the data points directly, and the data points are of different variety, so they have to be different kinds of Nodes.
- There are a few Nodes (BaseConnectedNodes) that have more than a few properties and are only 1 per Base Node.
- Then there are other Nodes (ConnectedNodes) that are generally multiple and have very few properties. So these Nodes are passed as lists and using FOREACH or UNWIND then created or matched using MERGE, then linked to the BaseNode.

```
MERGE (b: BaseNode {k_id: $b.k_id, value: $b.value})
    ON CREATE
    SET b = $b
    ON MATCH
    SET b += $b
MERGE (b1: BaseConnectedNodeType1 {k_id: $b.k_id, value: $b1.value})
    ON CREATE
        SET b1 = $b1
    ON MATCH
        SET b1.sources = CASE WHEN NOT 'source' IN b1.sources THEN b1.sources + 'source' END
MERGE (b)-[:baseConnectionType1]->(b1)
MERGE (b2: BaseConnectedNodeType2 {k_id: $b.k_id, value: $b2.value})
    ON CREATE
        SET b2 = $b2
    ON MATCH
        SET b2.value1 = $b2.value1,
            b2.value2 = $b2.value2,
            b2.value3 = $b2.value3,
            b2.sources = CASE WHEN NOT 'source' IN b2.sources THEN b2.sources + 'source' END
MERGE (b)-[:baseConnectionType2]->(b2)
MERGE (b3: BaseConnectedNodeType3 {k_id: $b.k_id, value: $b3.value})
    ON CREATE
        SET b3 = $b3
    ON MATCH
        SET b3.value1 = $b3.value1,
            b3.value2 = $b3.value2,
            b3.sources = CASE WHEN NOT 'source' IN b3.sources THEN b3.sources + 'source' END
MERGE (b)-[:baseConnectionType3]->(b3)
FOREACH (x in $x_list |
    MERGE (x1: ConnectedNodeType1 {
        k_id: $b.k_id,
        value: x
    })
        ON CREATE
            SET x1.sources = ['source']
        ON MATCH
            SET x1.sources = CASE WHEN NOT 'source' IN x1.sources THEN x1.sources + 'source' END
    MERGE (p)-[:connectionType1]->(x1))
FOREACH (y in $y_list |
    MERGE (y1: ConnectedNodeType2 {
        k_id: $b.k_id,
        value: y
    })
        ON CREATE
            SET y1.sources = ['source']
        ON MATCH
            SET y1.sources = CASE WHEN NOT 'source' IN y1.sources THEN y1.sources + 'source' END
    MERGE (p)-[:connectionType2]->(y1))
FOREACH (z in $z_list |
    MERGE (z1: ConnectedNodeType3 {
        k_id: $b.k_id,
        value: z
    })
        ON CREATE
            SET z1.sources = ['source']
        ON MATCH
            SET z1.sources = CASE WHEN NOT 'source' IN z1.sources THEN z1.sources + 'source' END
    MERGE (p)-[:connectionType3]->(z1))
```

Here is a sample query, we have several such queries.

I did post the same on Neo4j Discord, and someone suggested that I eliminate Eager Operations in my Query. So I broke the query down to multiple smaller queries making sure None of them had any Eager operations. But they are still very slow, actually slower than the original query.

Comment: How many nodes and relationships are expected to get created at minimum, in a single query?

Comment: Minimum could be pretty low, ~20 maybe. It really depends on the data the API returns.

Comment: Any indexes present in the database?

Comment: Yep, all the k_id and value are indexed.

Comment: ok, seems like everything is covered, is it a composite index ? or a single property index.

Comment: It is a composite index for both properties.

Comment: What's the output of EXPLAIN (or best, PROFILE) on your request ? PROFILE can tell you it's the bad performance is due too missing indexes, too many db hits, a lot of cache miss, etc.

Comment: The problem is solved. Had to break down the query into smaller parts, create all Nodes first, and then create all relationships separately. Now the performance is much much better, and acceptable.

Thanks for all the insights.